# app.use(validator()) TypeError: validator is not a function

Tags: node.js, express

Hi Every One I'm Trying To Install express-validator in my app But I'm Facing `TypeError: validator is not a function` When I Tried To Require The Moduleand Use It In app.use() Function

`app.js` Code

```
var validator = require("express-validator");

---

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));      app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(validator());
```

Comment: which version of express-validator are you trying to use? The answer might depend on that, since the initialisation can be different in different versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require("express-validator")` is not a middleware. The middlewares are:

```
check([field, message])

body([fields, message])

oneOf(validationChains[, message]) ..etc..
```

Basic example taken from [doc](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/index.html):

```
// ...rest of the initial code omitted for simplicity.
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

app.post('/user', [
  // username must be an email
  check('username').isEmail(),
  // password must be at least 5 chars long
  check('password').isLength({ min: 5 })
], (req, res) => {
  // Finds the validation errors in this request and wraps them in an object with handy functions
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }

  User.create({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  }).then(user => res.json(user));
});
```